# Using spatie/laravel-analytics, how do I get page views for a specific pagePath?

Tags: laravel, google-analytics, analytics

I've just started looking at spatie/laravel-analytics, a package for getting data out of Google Analytics API. I'm a bit lost right now though as documentation seems thin... either that or I'm not searching for the right things.

What I want to do *feels* like it should be quite simple, **get page views for each day over a period for a specific URL**.

My current code block looks like this:

```
$analyticsData = Analytics::performQuery(
    Period::days(7),
    'ga:pageviews',
    [
        'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/pasta-recipes/lasagne/'
    ]
    
);
var_dump($analyticsData);
```

As always, any help appreciated.

Comment: have you checked googles api for this? as any query that isn't shown in the docs as "examples" for this package you have to call yourself `performQuery(...)`

Comment: I've looked at lots of different pages from google, stackoverflow, etc - alot of the results either just don't work or turn out to be something different to what I was looking for. I've been looking at performQuery(...) and while I can see that is what I need to use I don't seem to be able to find an example of what I'm looking for - part of the problem being I'm not sure what specifically to search for... cheers.

Comment: Added my current code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, just to replace this:

```
'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath'
```

in:

```
'dimensions' => 'ga:date'
```

Output example:

[image]

Comment: How about total views? Any idea? Not per day but total views? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use structure of function Analytics::fetchVisitorsAndPageViews(Period::days(7)); but use pagePath

```
 $response = Analytics::performQuery(
    Period::days(7),
    'ga:users,ga:pageviews',
    ['dimensions' => 'ga:date,ga:pagePath']
);
$analyticsData = collect($response['rows'] ?? [])->map(function (array $dateRow) {
    return [
        'date' => Carbon::createFromFormat('Ymd', $dateRow[0]),
        'url' => $dateRow[1],
        'visitors' => (int) $dateRow[2],
        'pageViews' => (int) $dateRow[3],
    ];
});
    dd($analyticsData);
```